# RID master role Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003

When setting up a dev environment we copied an Active directory DC.
The original setup was 3 AD servers in a forest but i seized all master roles to the copied machine.
When running dcdiag it tells me this about the RID master role:

```
Starting test: RidManager
   * Available RID Pool for the Domain is 15103 to 1073741823
   * SRVDS004.xxx.local is the RID Master
   * DsBind with RID Master was successful
   * rIDAllocationPool is 14603 to 15102
   * rIDPreviousAllocationPool is 14603 to 15102
   * rIDNextRID: 15102
   * Warning :Next rid pool not allocated
   * Warning :There is less than 0% available RIDs in the current pool
   ......................... SRVDS004 passed test RidManager
```

It seems that RID next pool is empty.. I checked for DNS problems but they al seemed ok. Also i removed all reference to the other 2 DC's.

It has never worked since we copied it, but we only noticed it now because our SID's ran out because there are no RID's available in the pool and out 500 batch is empty..

Is there a way to check if that master role is realy running instead of this output which says it is running but doesn't seem to tell about why the problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

These links might help you:

1. [AD Internals: Display RID Allocation Pools](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2011/06/27/ad-internals-display-rid-allocation-pools/)
2. [AD Internals: Reset RID Allocation Pool](http://www.peppercrew.nl/index.php/2011/07/ad-internals-reset-rid-allocation-pool/)

The first link is a blog I wrote that explains how the RID mechanism works in Active Directory. The second link is another blog I wrote and this explains how to reset the RID Allocation Pool and includes a PowerShell script to reset the RID Allocation Pool.

Answer (score 0):

The RID master responsible for distributing non over lapin blocks of 500 hundreds RID's between the DC's of the domain. This is done to eliminate RID conflicts between different objects created on different DC's at the same time.